# setting base fontsize to 9

Tags: fonts, fontsize

Is it possible to set base font-size to <10 as in newspapers.

Here is sample code

```
\documentclass[9pts]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are choosing `scrartcl`,  instead of `article`you could do that.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options,

1. Use another document class, such as Koma-script as in @Jan's answer
2. If you want to stick to the standard class, you can define your own `\normalsize` etc.

A minimal example is,

```
\def\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{9}{11pt}}
```

In standard class' definition of `\normalsize` there are other stuff, such as display skips, etc. You would probably like to redefine `\small` etc similar.